# Error 500 when inserting a document in Google Drive with a service account

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to use Google Drive API to insert and read files in Google Drive from my Java application. I use a service account.

I have created a project in my Google API console, enabled the "Drive API" service, created a new service account, and used the downloaded private key in my application :

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(this.serviceEmail)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(this.privateKeyFilePath))
            .build();
```

Then my Drive service is instantiated with :

```
Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null)
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
            .build();
```

This works fine, I can insert, share, read files in Google Drive.

My problem is that I created a second project in my Google API console, did the same steps, but can't make it work. My 2 projects look identical, but with the second, I always have an error response when I try to insert a new document :

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}

at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:978)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:237)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:309)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
```

The first project has been created 6 months ago, whereas the second (which does not wrok) has been created these days.

How can I get more details about this error ? What can cause this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by a bad file format.
Try to upload the file directly in Google Drive and get a more detailed message.
I've had the following message:
"The uploaded file has the wrong format specification - for example, you might be trying to upload a CSV file as a XLS file."

However, I don't know how you can get more details about the error via the API. If anyone knows, let me know!